# Avoid downcast in this abstract factory using generics

Tags: java, design-patterns, generics, refactoring

I have the below objects

```
interface Adapter<T> {
      T fromXml(XML xml);
      XML toXml(T obj); //ignoring this in implementations
}

abstract class AbstractAdapter<T> implements Adapter<T>{
       T fromXml(XML xml) { //template method
         validate(xml);
         return parse(xml);
       }
       abstract void validate(Xml xml);
       abstract T parse(Xml xml);
}

class MyObjectAdapter extends AbstractAdapter<MyObject> {
       MyObject parse(XMl xml) {return null;}
       void validate(Xml xml) {}
}

class AnotherObjectAdapter extends AbstractAdapter<AnotherObject> {
       AnotherObject parse(XMl xml) {return null;}
       void validate(Xml xml) {}
}

class AdapterFactory {
      Adapter<?> createAdapter(String objectType) {
         if (objectType == "MyObject") return new MyObjectAdapter();
         if (objectType == "AnotherObject") return new AnotherObjectAdapter();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
      AdapterFactory factory = new AdapterFactory();
      //********
      Adapter<MyObject> myobjectAdapter = (Adapater<MyObject>) factory.createAdapter("MyObject");
      MyObject obj = myobjectAdapter.fromXml(getXml(args)); 
}
```

How do I avoid the downcasting I do in the line marked ******** above?
The objects that need to have an adapter do not have any relation between them, they are generic data objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an class name in a `String` and you're trying to go from that to the actual type. That is always going to involve a cast. If you remove the `AdapterFactory` and hence the `String`, then there is no problem.

(Usual note that `==` on `String`s isn't typically what you want.)

Comment: I need AdapterFactory, is there anything else I can pass instead of string like the class itself to avoid this?

Comment: @Arvind You could pass in a `Class`, but at best you'd still end up using that to cast (with a bit of fiddling about). You could use a relatively standard form of map that maps `Class<T>` to `Something<T>`. But really, if you want a `MyObject` the type you get it from should involve `MyObject`.